# Find the next missing date in the list

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a list of booking date stored in a table like so

```
1/1/2020
1/2/2020
1/3/2020
1/4/2020
1/6/2020
1/7/200
1/9/2020
```

I am trying to find the first missing date to get the next availability of the booking. I've the following code

```
$this->inventory->addSelect(['next_available' => InventoryBookingItem::query()
    ->selectRaw('CASE WHEN date IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) END')
    ->whereColumn('inventory_id', 'inventories.id')
    ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
    ->limit(1)
]);
```

This get me the `1/10/2020` but I need to consider the gaps as well in the table. How can I achieve this from Query?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider following example:

```
// create period for which you want to check for available dates
$period = new DatePeriod(
  new DateTime(),
  new DateInterval('P1D'),
  new DateTime('+1 month')
);
// your booked dates
$bookedDates = [
  '2020-07-16',
  '2020-07-17',
  '2020-07-19',
  '2020-07-21',
  '2020-07-26',
  '2020-08-01',
];

$dates = array_map(static function (DateTime $date) {
  return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}, iterator_to_array($period));

return array_diff($dates, $bookedDates); // it will return all available dates
```